# maven archetype generation with custom root folder name

Tags: maven

I am using `mvn archetype:generate` and I am supplying as input parameters the artifactId as well as the repositoryName that I want to use for git. I would like that the root folder name of the project generated is the repositoryName and not the artifactId, which is the default behavior.

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html), you can create a post generation groovy script that does different actions and moving the project to a new folder is also possible, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65413546/811257). This solution worked out for me. However, right after the output of my script, there is the default log line that says

```
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: <old_dir>
```

This is very confusing and I'm wondering if there is a way to change that. Maybe changing the `request.outputDirectory` would provide a better solution, but I didn't manage to get that to work and I am also wondering what is a good structural solution.

Comment: Are you sure you want that? It is the standard to name the folder like the generated artifact. Everything else will confuse people.

Comment: I want the folder to be aligned with the folder name in git. This is the default behavior when I clone the repo that somebody else created, my local folder has the same name as the repo. So yes, I want that to be aligned too. I have way too many repos and having the artifactId would be confusing because I have no way of knowing this in advance before opening the project

Comment: Why are your git repositories not named as the artifactIds?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. When i do git clone, the local folder generated is always lowercase. I want the same for the projects I create myself, a lowercase folder

Comment: ArtifactIds are lower case by the usual convention. So there is no real contradiction here. ArtifactIds usually consist of lower case letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) and/or a hyphen (-).